# Why won't my text float to the right?

Tags: html, css, text

Basically I wanted the Sign in link to be on the right and my logo to be where it is. I'm still a newbie at CSS and I've tried all that I could think of in terms of the code. Here's the HTML:

```
<!--header-->
    <div id="header">
        <a href="#" id="logo">IMG</a>
        <a href="" id="signIn">Sign into CGC!</a>   
    </div>
```

And here is the CSS:

```
#div header{
font-family; sans-serif;

}
#div a signIn{
    float: right;
}
```

Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Your selectors are incorrect:

```
div#header{
  font-family; sans-serif;
}

div#header a#signIn{
  float: right;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you've assigned an ID you can just use:

```
 #signIn{
    float: right;
 }
```

Your code specifies a 'signIn' element, that is a child of an anchor element, that is a child of an element with the ID 'div'. Hope that's clear.

Same goes for the header

```
 #header{ 
   font-family; sans-serif;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this code:

**[Fiddle:](http://jsfiddle.net/27fSN/)**

CSS:

```
div#header{
font-family; sans-serif;

}
div a#signIn{
    float: right;
}
```